# What does red circle with white exclamation mark mean in Firefox console?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

[image: Red circle with exclamation mark in Firefox console]

I don't have a code example code to replicate this. There's a tooltip showing on hover which says "Show split console" and the console itself doesn't log anything new until I clear it.

Normally I would expect an error and a trace with files and code lines causing it.

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation mark with the number in it indicates the number of errors logged to the [Web Console](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/). When you click this icon, the [Split Console](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/split_console/index.html) opens up showing you the different log messages.

Here's an example of how this Split Console looks like:

[image: Split console opened via the errors badge]

If you *don't* see the errors listed in there, this might be because the list of log messages can be long and you have to scroll it to see them. Or you have the filter for error messages disabled (marked in green in the screenshot).